# RegularExpressionAttribute Not Working and I Don't Know Why

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-2, attributes

I have a simple view model class for MVC2 that has a MagicItem property:

```
public class VoodooViewModel {

  [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, 
            ErrorMessage = "The Magic Item is required")]
  [RegularExpression(@"^[^-]*$", 
                     ErrorMessage = "Hyphens are not allowed in Magic Items.")]
  public string MajorModel { get; set; }
}
```

I am simply trying to disallow hyphens in this property, but for the life of me I can't get it to work.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong (the RequiredAttribute is working fine)?

To my eyes, the regex I have says "from the beginning of the string to the end, match anything that isn't a hyphen".  I have tested this in the Regex tester [here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx), and it works - but not in my code. I can't get the error to show no matter how many hyphens I put in it.

Comment: The problem must be somewhere else as this code worked when I tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a tool, I forgot to check in the controller's action method to see if the ModelState was valid or not:

```
public ActionResult UberController(VoodooViewModel vvm)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(vvm);  //turns out this line is important

  (...yaddayaddayadda...)
}
```

Thanks to [Darin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) for pointing me in the right direction.